# Create an animation that plots the following two functions

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

How do I create an animation that plots the following two functions? Let x vary from 0 to 15, set the y-values to range from -90 to 90 and include the fill between them. Do not include the axes in the plot.
f(x) = x^2 - a*x + 20 + a where a varies from 10 to 15.
g(x) = -x^2 + bx + b where b varies from 15 to 10.

I've tried `Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, a], g[x, b], {x, 0, 15}], {a, 10, 15}, {b, 15, 10}]`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You call `f` and `g` with two arguments, but they are only defined for a single argument. After fixing several typos, this seems to work:

```
f[x_, a_] := x^2 - a x + 20 + a;
g[x_, b_] := -x^2 + b x + b;
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[{f[x, a], g[x, b]}], {x, 0, 15}],
 {a, 10, 15}, {b, 10, 15}
 ]
```

Comment: Nice answer!  You can also keep the axes from moving with `PlotRange->{-100,100}` within `Plot`.

Comment: With `Filling` and other items: `Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {f[x, a], g[x, b]}, {x, 0, 15},
  Axes -> False,
  PlotRange -> {-90, 90},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  PlotLegends ->
   Placed[{f[x, a], g[x, b]}, {0.2, 0.15}]],
 {a, 10, 15, 0.1}, {b, 15, 10, -0.1},
 AutoAction -> True]`

Comment: Thank you so much guys :)

Comment: You're welcome.